# Moq тестирование модели БД с HttpContext.Current.Request.GetOwinContext() asp.net

Tags: asp.net, moq

Есть модель базы данных Doc, которая содержит вызов HttpContext.Current.Request.GetOwinContext():

```
public class Doc
{
    private DBaseContext db;
    private OracleContext oracle;

    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string DocNum { get; set; }

    public int UserId { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public DateTime DocDate { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public string Status { get; set; }

    public Doc()
    {
        db = HttpContext.Current.Request.GetOwinContext().Get<DBaseContext>();
        oracle = HttpContext.Current.Request.GetOwinContext().Get<OracleContext>();
    }

    public List<Oper> GetOpers() => oracle.GetOpersList(this.DocNum);

    }
}
```

Есть API контроллер Docs с  методами, которые обращаются к этой модели, например:

```
        [HttpGet]
    [ResponseType(typeof(List<ViewDoc>))]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Get()
    {
        User user = await UserManager.FindByIdAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId<int>());
        var docs = Mapper.Map<List<Doc>, List<ViewDoc>>(db.Docs.Where(s => s.UserId == user.Id).ToList());
        return Ok(docs);
    }
```

Я создала IDBaseContextс этой модели, и тест с заполнением модели:

```
 public interface IDBaseContext : IDisposable
{
    DbSet<Doc> Docs { get; set; }

    int SaveChanges();
    void MarkAsModified(object item);
}
     private Doc doc = new Doc
     {
         Id = 1,
         DocNum = "12345",
         DocDate = DateTime.Parse("13.06.2018"),
         Status = "Действует",
         UserId = 1
     };
```

На строчке "private Doc doc = new Doc" тест выдает ошибку: HttpContext is null.
Я пробовала добавить в контроллер HttpControllerContext с OwinContext, но это не помогло.
Как протестировать  эту модель, или как изолировать её правильно?

Comment: Простите, но это бред какой-то... Судя по строке `DbSet<Doc> Docs` - Doc является _сущностью_, которая хранится в БД. Но в то же время `Doc` содержит в себе контексты для работы с БД: `DBaseContext db; OracleContext oracle;`

Comment: Конечно, можно сказать, что это паттерн Active record, когда записи сами себя пишут в БД и читают оттуда. Но он сильно критикуется и не рекомендуется именно из-за сложностей, с которыми вы столкнулись.

Comment: Главное правило тестируемого дизайна: low coupling - слабая связанность. Сервисы не должны создаваться внутри классов, они должны получаться снаружи. Нужно реализовать Dependency injection - инъекцию зависимостей. Нужны внутри `Doc` какие-то контексты - передайте их в конструкторе. Тогда можно будет легко подсунуть мок.

Comment: Полезные ссылки: [Testing EF Core Applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/testing/), [Unit test controller logic in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/testing?view=aspnetcore-7.0)